# Options available in Java for printing other than Java Printing Services

Tags: java, printing

I have a requirement to send details on my page for Print using Java. On click , Print Job popup will display available Printer details for user to select

Option available - Java Print Service(**but printlookupservice method is not returning required result**)

Case 1. Working fine on my local machine application deployed on pramati server.

Case 2. Returning incorrect result for application running on WAS server. Method job.getPrintService() return some **printer Id with name Unix Printer -Result should display same printer??**

Other Issues found on net -- **access issues, migration issue** ..on changing deployed server or version update.

Please suggest **if there is any option available in Java to do print Job to overcome above cases**

Thanks in advance

Comment: How would the remote server have your local printer configuration?

Comment: how we implement print option in Web applications ??